# Requests stopped by new paragraph

Tags: python, html, request, screen-scraping

I have the following problem scraping data from a website, the Text that gets returned is cut off by a

```
  <p> blabla </p>
```

in the source code.
How do i get request to return me the text before AND in it?

Code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://sitetoscrape.com')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

#Mitglieder
members = tree.xpath('//div[@class="details"]/text()')

print 'Mitglieder: ', members
```

example:
in HTML:

```
<div class="details">Altherr Hans<br /><br />
Kanton Appenzell A.-Rh.<p>FDP-Liberale Fraktion (RL)<br />
FDP.Die  Liberalen (FDP-Liberale) </p>
```

what I get from the code above:

```
'Altherr Hans', '\r\n 
Kanton Appenzell A.-Rh.',
```

Comment: You have to provide more details to the question.

Comment: added an example of the html code in question and the return i get from the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add /text in the xpath. tree.xpath will generate a list of html elements. Iterating over it and getting the text content will create the required result.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://sitetoscrape.com')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

#Mitglieder
members = tree.xpath('//div[@class="details"]')

for i in members:
    print i.text_content()
```